# How to change a global variable of a workbook by activating a macro from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel files, a **patcher.xlsm** and a **file.xlsm**. There is a button on **file.xlsm**, when it clicks it executes a procedure on Sheet 1 with a message box: *The magic number is: 5*.

Now, I have a **patcher.xlsm**, that would re-import a patched Sheet 1 and a Standard module with a global variable and run a macro on **file.xlsm** to set this number to 7. The expected result is such that, users clicking on **file.xlsm** would now see *The magic number is: 7*.

For some reason, whenever I executed **patcher.xlsm**, the magic number is always reset to 0, as though the memory has been cleared or project reset.

Is there a way to assign a global variable from another workbook?

In the past, I have looked at several stackoverflow threads, example, changing the scope of the variable, private, public, global, etc, activating the workbook, looking at Excel's hidden name space at the moment.

```
Sub Proc()
  MsgBox "The magic number is: 5"
End Sub
```

**Sheet1 in file.xlsm**

```
Call CopyModule("patcher_b_progress_bar.xlsm", "file_b.xlsm", "Sheet1", True)
Call CopyModule("patcher_b_progress_bar.xlsm", "file_b.xlsm", "GlobalModule", True)
Application.Run ("'file_b.xlsm'!GlobalModule.setDefaultMagicNumber")
```

**patcher.xlsm "patching" the sheet 1 and setting a magic number via a module**

```
CopyModule 
' export "patched GlobalModule" from patcher.xlsm as temp.bas
' remove GlobalModule from file.xlsm
' re-import "patched GlobalModule" to file.xlsm
(too lengthy to post here, referenced from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)
```

**CopyModule of patcher.xlsm**

```
Option Explicit

Private MAGIC_NUMBER As Integer

Public Function getMagicNumber() As Integer
    getMagicNumber = MAGIC_NUMBER 
End Function

Public Function setDefaultMagicNumber() As Integer
    MAGIC_NUMBER = 7
    setDefaultMagicNumber= getMagicNumber()
End Function
```

**GlobalModule of patcher.xlsm**

```
Sub Proc()
  If GlobalModule.getMagicNumber= 7 Then
    MsgBox "Magic number is correct: " & GlobalModule.getMagicNumber
  Else
    MsgBox "Magic number is wrong: " & GlobalModule.getMagicNumber
  End If
End Sub
```

**Sheet1 of patcher.xlsm (to be overwritten to file.xlsm)**

EDIT: I have modified the issue. It seems like the variable MAGIC_NUMBER is re-initialise to "0" even though the line "GlobalModule.setDefaultMagicNumber" is executed successfully.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to put the magic number in an external file rather than attempting to rewrite a VBA module on the fly.

Comment: @Freeflow The aim of the code is used to patch out-dated macros. It happens that some version of the macros don't have the specific modules. An external file is not a viable option. It would definitely be simpler and works out of the box but I am looking more of a vba solution.

Comment: My guess is that if you are changing the source code then the module will be recompiled, hence any values set in the original code will be lost.  As far as I can see you are not executing the setmagicnumber procedure after patching the code so your getmagicnumber procedure will return the default value for an unitialised integer, which is 0.

Comment: @Freeflow The setMagicNumber is invoked after the patching the module. I guess what you mentioned makes sense as it is logical for the memory space to be cleared but the fact that I tried to re-assign the global variable after the patch and it still doesn't register, scratches my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO and Congratulation for asking a real good question

This is only a part solution and not at all any where near to satisfaction. However i am posting it, since it would somehow serve your purpose of code to change Magic_Number to some desired integer.

I tried it some different setup with slightly different objective (which could not be achieved).

In `File.Xlsm` Workbook Open event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
SetMagic
End Sub
```

In Module1 of `File.Xlsm`

```
Global Magic_Number As Integer
Sub Test_Magic()
MsgBox Magic_Number
End Sub

Sub SetMagic()
Magic_Number = 5
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F1").Value = Magic_Number
End Sub
```

In Sheet1 Change Event of `File.Xlsm`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:E20"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Magic_Number = Magic_Number + 1
    Range("F1").Value = Magic_Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally in `Patch.xlsm` Module1

```
Sub ChangeMagic()
Dim wb As Workbook, Opn As Boolean , Ln as Long
    Onp = False
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name = "File.xlsm" Then
    Opn = True
    Exit For
    End If
    Next

    If Opn = False Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File.xlsm")
    End If


    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
    Ln = .ProcBodyLine("SetMagic", vbext_pk_Proc)
    .ReplaceLine Ln + 1, "Magic_number =  100"
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "'File.xlsm'!Module1.SetMagic"
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

The line

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "'File.xlsm'!Module1.SetMagic"
```

do the trick. after replacing the required code line in VBE, macro in `Patch.xlsm` ends and `SetMagic` get executed after a delay when `File.xlsm` activated. Magic_Number will be 100.

But it still not serve my intended purpose as during trials it become evident that Magic_Number is resetting to 0 as soon the VBE code module line is replaced (i.e. before executing `Sub SetMagic`). But your purpose will be solved and Magic_Number is getting any value we set from `Patch.xlsm`.

For my objective of dynamically setting `Magic_Number = Magic_Number + 100` could not be achieved. For achieving that purpose, i have to workaround and keep the latest value of Magic_Number stored in some cell etc and retrieve from there (that will loose real spirit of the code intended)

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed! I observed an interesting thing! When I modified the code from ```Application.Run...``` to ```Application.OnTime...``` the magic number was successfully modified. If I switched it back, the magic number was reset to 0 again. Not sure what is the difference between these two APIs; definitely not the time delay because I attempted with an ```Application.Wait...``` after the  ```Call CopyModule``` but it just worked.

Comment: with `Application.wait`  application simply wait before progressing to next line of code, whereas `Application.OnTime` schedule running the targeted macro in a future time and  continue execution of remaining code (in this case it activate `File.Xlsm` and ends execution of Macro in `Patch.xlsm`)